# Push Notifications is not in Capabilities any More iOS

Tags: ios, push-notification

I am trying to turn on the "Push Notification" in Capabilities but the push notification is not there any more.  Does any one knows where I can find it or how can get it back?

Thanks

Comment: From what I know, it is still there *(Xcode 8)* https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/Art/4_capabilitieseditor_2x.png. Did you try to restart the Xcode?

Comment: Not really...maybe I need first get the certificate.